# How to get feature importance from RandomForest using scikit-multilearn library?

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am working on multi-label classification problem, binary case. As a target variable there are five columns with 0-1 values.

For a model training I use [scikit-multilearn library](http://scikit.ml/). Below is my code for training a model with Binary Relevance and RandomForest.

```
parameters = [
{
    'classifier': [RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)],

    'classifier__n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
    'classifier__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'classifier__max_depth' : [4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
    'classifier__criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']}]

clf = RandomizedSearchCV(BinaryRelevance(), parameters, scoring='f1_weighted', cv=5, \
n_jobs=-1, verbose=10, random_state=10)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How could I extract feature importance from the model?
Should I take the best parameters from this model and then apply to data with each label separately using RandomForest from sklearn?

Answer (score 4):

First, to directly answer your question, the easiest way to get Feature Importance using scikit learn is this, where `model` is the variable holding your classifier.

```
print(model.feature_importances_)
```

However, this method only exists on some of the [Ensemble models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#ensemble), namely:

- AdaBoostClassifier
- AdaBoostRegressor
- ExtraTreesClassifier
- ExtraTreesRegressor
- GradientBoostingClassifer
- GradientBoostingRegressor
- RandomForestClassifier
- RandomForestRegressor
- RandomTreesEmbedding

If you're wondering why, there's a fantastic free book online all about [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/simple.html). Here's an excerpt:

> The easiest way to achieve interpretability is to use only a subset of
>   algorithms that create interpretable models. Linear regression,
>   logistic regression and the decision tree are commonly used
>   interpretable models.

Once you've chosen the right model, **beware of using feature importance!** [See here, it ranks random data very highly.](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/) The article proposes using Permutation Importance instead, as well as Drop-Column Importance.

They created a library called [rfpimp](https://github.com/parrt/random-forest-importances) for doing this, but [here's a tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html) from scikit themselves on how to do both of those with just scikit-learn. I've pasted the permutation importance example from that tutorial below:

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

result = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10,
                                random_state=42, n_jobs=2)
sorted_idx = result.importances_mean.argsort()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(result.importances[sorted_idx].T,
           vert=False, labels=X_test.columns[sorted_idx])
ax.set_title("Permutation Importances (test set)")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the article. Itis interesting and I upvoted for that. However, **BinaryRelevance** from **scikit-multilearn** library doesn't work with feature_importances_ method.

Comment: @Mirit You are correct, I've edited my answer to include which models are supported as well as an explanation of why. Thanks!